# Stuck on Astar Planner plugin for movebase to operate turtlebot3

Tags: ros, navigation, costmap, turtlebot3

I have a problem on my astar planner plugin for move_base to move the turtlebot3.

When I use the 2D nav goal, sometimes it works I don't know why but many times it doesn't. It does not make the path instead the turtlbot just rotates.
I think that the turtlebot does not find its starting point so it keeps rotating for recovery behavior.

I think that it is related to the OccupancyGridMap, which finds the free area except for the obstacles. However, I think that the logic is fine and I cannot figure out the problem. I think that the costmap can be the problem.
The default planner of move_base works fine but mine doesn't.

I uploaded the astar planner plugin algorithm(cpp,header) and screenshot of what I got when using the 2D nav goal

please Help me I am solving this problem a week ㅠㅠ

It is ROS Noetic and Ubuntu 20.04
[image]

```
#ifndef ASTAR_PLANNER_CPP
#define ASTAR_PLANNER_CPP

#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <costmap_2d/costmap_2d_ros.h>
#include <costmap_2d/costmap_2d.h>
#include <nav_core/base_global_planner.h>
#include <geometry_msgs/PoseStamped.h>
#include <angles/angles.h>
#include <base_local_planner/world_model.h>
#include <base_local_planner/costmap_model.h>
#include <nav_msgs/Path.h>
#include <tf/tf.h>
#include <vector>
#include <queue>
#include <cmath>

using std::string;
using std::vector;
using std::priority_queue;
using std::abs;

struct Node{
    double f_cost, g_cost;
    int idx;
};

namespace astar_planner {
    class AstarPlanner : public nav_core::BaseGlobalPlanner {
        public:
            bool initialized = false;
            costmap_2d::Costmap2DROS *m_costmap_ros;
            costmap_2d::Costmap2D *m_costmap;
            int cellsY;
            int cellsX;
            int area;
            vector<bool> OccupancyGridMap;
            vector<int> open;
            vector<bool> closed;
            vector<int> parentNode;
            string m_frame_id;
            ros::Publisher pub;
            AstarPlanner(); // default constructor
            AstarPlanner(std::string name, costmap_2d::Costmap2DROS* costmap_ros);

            /** overridden classes from interface nav_core::BaseGlobalPlanner **/
            void initialize(std::string name, costmap_2d::Costmap2DROS* costmap_ros);
            bool makePlan(const geometry_msgs::PoseStamped& start,const geometry_msgs::PoseStamped& goal,std::vector<geometry_msgs::PoseStamped>& plan);
            
            //helper methods
            vector<int> getAdjacent(int cur_idx);
            double getGcost(int fstIdx, int sndIdx);
            int getHeuristic(int nIdx, int goalIdx);
            bool areaLimit(int x, int y);
            void publishPlan(const std::vector<geometry_msgs::PoseStamped>& path);
            void mapToWorld(unsigned int mx, unsigned int my, double& wx, double& wy);
            bool worldToMap(double wx, double wy, unsigned int& mx, unsigned int& my);
    };
};

#endif
```

```
#include "AstarPlanner.h"
#include <pluginlib/class_list_macros.h>

//register this planner as a BaseAstarPlanner plugin
PLUGINLIB_EXPORT_CLASS(astar_planner::AstarPlanner, nav_core::BaseGlobalPlanner)

// compare function for minimum heap
struct cmp {
    bool operator()(Node &fst_node, Node &snd_node) {
        return fst_node.f_cost > snd_node.f_cost;
    }
};

//finding the adjacent nodes in the clockwise direction
int dx[8] = {0,1,1,1,0,-1,-1,-1};
int dy[8] = {-1,-1,0,1,1,1,0,-1};
namespace astar_planner {

    //Constructor
    AstarPlanner::AstarPlanner(){}

    AstarPlanner::AstarPlanner(std::string name, costmap_2d::Costmap2DROS* costmap_ros){
        initialize(name, costmap_ros);
    }

    //initialized the astar planner
    void AstarPlanner::initialize(std::string name, costmap_2d::Costmap2DROS* costmap_ros){
        if(!initialized) {
            m_costmap_ros = costmap_ros;
            m_costmap = m_costmap_ros->getCostmap();
            cellsY = m_costmap->getSizeInCellsY();
            cellsX = m_costmap->getSizeInCellsX();
            area = cellsY * cellsX;
            OccupancyGridMap.resize(area,false);
            for(unsigned int i = 0; i < cellsY; i++) {
                for(unsigned int j = 0; j < cellsX; j++) {
                    int cost = static_cast<int>(m_costmap->getCost(j,i));
                    if(cost == 0) {
                       OccupancyGridMap[i*cellsX+j] = true;
                    }
                    
                }
            }
            m_frame_id = m_costmap_ros->getGlobalFrameID();
            ros::NodeHandle private_nh("~/"+name);
            pub = private_nh.advertise<nav_msgs::Path>("plan", 1);
            initialized = true;
        }
        else {
            ROS_WARN("Already Initialized");

        }
    }

    //making the path of the AMR
    bool AstarPlanner::makePlan(const geometry_msgs::PoseStamped& start, const geometry_msgs::PoseStamped& goal,  std::vector<geometry_msgs::PoseStamped>& plan ){
        if(!initialized) {
            ROS_WARN("Not Initialized");
            return false;
        }
        //get the start pose of the map from the world
        double world_sx = start.pose.position.x;
        double world_sy = start.pose.position.y;
        unsigned int start_x,start_y;
        m_costmap->worldToMap(world_sx,world_sy,start_x,start_y);

        //get the goal pose of the map from the world
        double world_gx = goal.pose.position.x;
        double world_gy = goal.pose.position.y;
        unsigned int goal_x,goal_y;
        m_costmap->worldToMap(world_gx,world_gy,goal_x,goal_y);

        //convert to the index from the coordinates
        int start_idx = m_costmap->getIndex(start_x,start_y);
        int goal_idx = m_costmap->getIndex(goal_x,goal_y);
        
        //check the start and goal located at the correct poistion
        if(OccupancyGridMap[start_idx] == false || !areaLimit(start_x,start_y)) {
            ROS_WARN("%d  %d",start_y,start_x);
            ROS_WARN("Wrong start position");
            return false;
        }
        if(OccupancyGridMap[goal_idx] == false || !areaLimit(goal_x,goal_y)) {
            ROS_WARN("Wrong goal position");
            return false;
        }
        //pq to get the lowest value of the fuctions
        priority_queue<Node,vector<Node>,cmp> pq_wait;
        //make the open and closed checking vector for astar
        open.resize(area,2000000);
        closed.resize(area,false);

        //make the parent node
        parentNode.resize(area,-10);

        //make the start node
        Node start_node;
        start_node.f_cost = 0 + getHeuristic(start_idx,goal_idx);
        start_node.g_cost = 0;
        start_node.idx = start_idx;
        open[start_idx] = start_node.f_cost;
        parentNode[start_idx] = -1;
        pq_wait.push(start_node);
        
        //find the path and allocate it to the parentNode
        while(!pq_wait.empty()) {
            Node cur = pq_wait.top();
            pq_wait.pop();
            if(closed[cur.idx]== true) {
                continue;
            }
            if(cur.idx == goal_idx) {
                break;
            }
            closed[cur.idx] = true;
            vector<int> adj = getAdjacent(cur.idx);
            for(int i = 0; i < adj.size(); i++) {
                Node nxt;
                nxt.idx = adj[i];
                if(closed[nxt.idx]) {
                    continue;
                }
                nxt.g_cost = cur.g_cost + getGcost(cur.idx,nxt.idx);
                nxt.f_cost = nxt.g_cost + getHeuristic(nxt.idx,goal_idx);
                
                if(open[nxt.idx] < nxt.f_cost) {
                    continue;
                }
                
                open[nxt.idx] = nxt.f_cost;
                parentNode[nxt.idx] = cur.idx;
                pq_wait.push(nxt);
            }
        }
        
        if(parentNode[goal_idx] == -10) {
            ROS_WARN("%d", parentNode[goal_idx]);
            ROS_WARN("Goal pose cannot be reached");
            return false;
        }
        
        //construct the path
        vector<int> path;
        int reverse_start = goal_idx;
        while(parentNode[reverse_start] != -1) {
            path.push_back(reverse_start);
            reverse_start = parentNode[reverse_start];
        }
        path.push_back(start_idx);
        reverse(path.begin(),path.end());

        //make the final plan
        ros::Time plan_time = ros::Time::now();
        for(int i = 0; i < path.size(); i++) {
            unsigned int tmp_x,tmp_y;
            m_costmap->indexToCells(path[i],tmp_x,tmp_y);
            double cur_x,cur_y;
            m_costmap->mapToWorld(tmp_x,tmp_y,cur_x,cur_y);

            m_costmap->indexToCells(path[i-1],tmp_x,tmp_y);
            double prev_x,prev_y;
            m_costmap->mapToWorld(tmp_x,tmp_y,prev_x,prev_y);
            double angle = atan2(cur_y-prev_y,cur_x-prev_x);

            geometry_msgs::PoseStamped coord;
            coord.header.stamp = plan_time;
            coord.header.frame_id = m_costmap_ros->getGlobalFrameID();
            coord.pose.position.x = cur_x;
            coord.pose.position.y = cur_y;
            coord.pose.position.z = 0.0;

            coord.pose.orientation = tf::createQuaternionMsgFromYaw(angle);
            plan.push_back(coord);
        }
        return true;
    }

    //find the adjacent nodes
    vector<int> AstarPlanner::getAdjacent(int cur_idx) {
        vector<int> adj;
        unsigned int cur_x, cur_y;
        m_costmap->indexToCells(cur_idx,cur_x,cur_y);
        for(int dir = 0; dir < 8; dir++) {
            int nx = cur_x+dx[dir];
            int ny = cur_y+dy[dir];
            if(!areaLimit(nx,ny)) {
                continue;
            }
            int nidx = m_costmap->getIndex(nx,ny);
            if(OccupancyGridMap[nidx] == false) {
                continue;
            }
            adj.push_back(nidx);
        }
        return adj;
    }

    // get the g function value of the adjacent nodes
    double AstarPlanner::getGcost(int fstIdx, int sndIdx) {
        unsigned int tmp_x,tmp_y;
        m_costmap->indexToCells(fstIdx,tmp_x,tmp_y);
        int fst_x = tmp_x;
        int fst_y = tmp_y;

        m_costmap->indexToCells(sndIdx,tmp_x,tmp_y);
        int snd_x = tmp_x;
        int snd_y = tmp_y;
        int cost = abs(fst_x-snd_x) + abs(fst_y-snd_y);
        if(cost == 2) {
            // pythagorean theorem
            return 1.4;
        }
        else {
            return 1.0;
        }
    }

    // get the heuristic function value
    int AstarPlanner::getHeuristic(int nIdx, int goalIdx) {
        unsigned int tmp_x,tmp_y;
        m_costmap->indexToCells(nIdx,tmp_x,tmp_y);
        int nx = tmp_x;
        int ny = tmp_y;

        m_costmap->indexToCells(goalIdx,tmp_x,tmp_y);
        int gx = tmp_x;
        int gy = tmp_y;

        return (abs(nx-gx)+abs(ny-gy));
    }

    //check the limitation of the map size
    bool AstarPlanner::areaLimit(int x, int y) {
        if(x < 0 || y < 0 || x >= cellsX || y >= cellsY) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
};
```

Comment: Please add your comment as an answer, then click the answer's checkmark to turn it green. On this site, it is fine to answer your own question if you figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed the issue it was about the costmap inflation radius parameter. It was too huge so that the start position of the turtlebot was not on the free space area.